# How to handle near-simultaneous opposing event functions

Tags: javascript

```
var userA = 10;
var userB = 10;
var users = [userA, userB];

function user(defence, attack){
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  if (users[i] == userA) {
    if (defence == attack) {
      return 0;
 } }

  //Attack is undefended and hurts the defender
  if (attack == "head") {
    return users[i] -= 4;
  } else if (attack == "leg") {
    return users[i] -= 2;
  }

else if (users[i] == userB) {
  if (defence == attack) {
    return 0;
 } }

  //Attack is undefended and hurts the defender
  if (attack == "head") {
    return users[i] -= 4;
  } else if (attack == "leg") {
    return users[i] -= 2;
  }



}

}

users[i] += user("head", "leg");
```

---

As you can see, i'm trying to write a very basic javascript 1-to-1 combat game, but i'm struggling..My code is not very fuctional.

**How I can make the "attack" function and "defend" function interconnected ? For example;
User A: targets User B's head
User A: meanwhile, defends his head from his opponent as well
User B: defends his head, therefore User A's damage is not done
User B: meanwhile, attacks User A's legs and does 3 points damage to the User A**

This is my own project in which Im trying to develop my coding skills :) Hope you understood my question! If not, I can clafiry a bit more.
Thanks

Comment: Off topic: As you can see after I formatted your code you have structural problems, or maybe something's missing.

Comment: How will this game work? Will There be a graphical interface? I recommend you plan the whole game out without actually coding it. - pseudo code.

Comment: I suppose you'll need some sort of timer to compare the delay between attack and defend, and vice versa. There's really no such thing as a simultaneous event.

Comment: Hi, isherwood, thanks. But I don't know how it helps solving this problem :)
Manu - It will be just a browser based, small experimental game, with texts and some checkboxs

Comment: isherwood, I guess you're right. But i think maybe it can be solved with turn-based strategy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can make the "attack" function and "defend" function interconnected ?

```
function effect_of_attack(d_part, a_part){
  // Attack is defended, no effect
  if (d_part == a_part) {
    return 0;
  }

  //Attack is undefended and hurts the defender
  if (a_part == "head") {
    return -4;
  } else if (a_part == "leg") {
    return -2;
  }
}

//Assume d_part holds the defense's input ("leg" or "head")
//Assume a_part holds the attacker's input ("leg" or "head")

defenders_health += effect_of_attack(d_part, a_part);
```

Comment: This is good one! I'll be working on this one. But one more question, how could I make it work in a turn-based game ?

Comment: 1. Initialize game variables (player health, who is attacking first, etc.,)
2. Start the "game loop".  Each iteration of the loop represents a "turn".  So the start of the loop would be to get inputs from both users.  Then calculate the effect on the player's health.  Then check if either player's health is <=0 (the end condition), break out of the loop if the end condition is met.  Switch the attacker and defender at the end of every turn.
3.  After the while loop, this is where you would announce the winner.

Comment: I think  I messed it up a  lot @hkievet